# Continuous plot of time series during business hours in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with market data from 9:30 - 4:00 pm for about a month.  When I plot it using matplotlib, there are long flat areas corresponding to the hours when the market is closed every night, and even longer flat areas for the weekends.  Is there a way I can tell it to only plot during business hours so the flat areas go away?

### EDIT

The "duplicate answer" isn't a solution, it's a workaround.    And it's not even a good workaround, because it makes all the data evenly spaced without regard to the timestamp. What I'm wondering is if there is some type of calendar object which is aware of business hours and business days that I could use.  Sorry I wasn't more clear in my original post.

Comment: What's your code, how are you attempting to address your task - and why is there a `matlab` in the title?

Comment: I suppose [this section](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#skip-dates-where-there-is-no-data) of the matplotlib docs is what you're after?

Comment: I have no real idea of the problem you're trying to solve here but maybe you should add in addition a plot of the derivative?

Comment: You filter the dataframe for the relevant times, then plot just the filtered dataframe?

Comment: Not a duplicate question, and the proposed solution wouldn't work.  Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter your data first.  If you are for example plotting `activity` against `date` in the data frame `df` and you wish to exclude plotting `date` when `activity` is non-existant then you could...

```
df_activity = df[df['activity'] > 0].copy()
df_activity.plot(x='date', y='activity', kind='line')
```

This also takes advantage of [pandas plot method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which allows direct plotting of dataframes.

Alternatively you could filter out specific date/times if its possible that you have periods of zero `activity` during opening hours.